# DICOM video converter

Tags: matlab, video, dicom

I've recently get a set of medical videos data in DICOM format. The problem is that I know they should be videos but any DICOM program I've used till now, knows each video as a single image!

I've also tried MATLAB dicomreader to convert videos to stream of frames but the same problem occurs.

Does anyone know how can I convert my data to a known video format like avi, mpg, wmv,...?

Can the problem be the system(GEMS echocardiography) which has burnt data on CD? or maybe there must be a setting before writing...

Thank you all for your help and guides.

Comment: would you be able to post the original DICOM file?  my research is largely based on sets of echocardiographic data as well.

Comment: Sorry if I say this but it is not possible, because I'm not allowed to do so, the hospital restricted me to share datasets!

Comment: not even after HIPAA de-identification?  what i would suggest is to dcmdump the 'pixel-data' segment of the dicom file and see.  (http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/dcmdump.html).  However that can be tricky provided that the vendors could need you to export the pixel-data in the right format before you can do dcmdump.

Comment: Thank you Gary, I think it would be solving. I've found another system (a MEDISON ultrasound system) which gives avi output, I prefer these new technology than the old vivid7!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Imebra](http://imebra.com) has an example called dicom2jpeg that can also convert to video if you have ffmpeg installed on your pc.

The downside is that you have to compile the example yourself using QMake or QtCreator.

In the case that the originator really stored the video as a collection of single images, your best bet is still to use ffmpeg and give the bunch of images (converted to jpeg or png) as input.